# "'POWERBI_ROLE' specified in the connect string is not granted to this user....."

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm following the tutorial from here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Amplifying-Outcomes-with-Snowflake

In PowerBI Desktop, I'm trying to "Get Data" and receive the following error: Details: "ODBC: ERROR [28000] Role 'POWERBI_ROLE' specified in the connect string is not granted to this user. Contact your local system administrator, or attempt to login with another role, e.g. PUBLIC.

ERROR [28000] Role 'POWERBI_ROLE' specified in the connect string is not granted to this user. Contact your local system administrator, or attempt to login with another role, e.g. PUBLIC."

1. In snowflake I've added the role to the user by using the query:
   ALTER USER POWERBI_USER_ACCOUNT SET DEFAULT_ROLE=POWERBI_ROLE;
2. I've done this multiple times in snowflake, and did not receive an
   error.
3. I've tried editing the ODBC connection in the "ODBC Data Source
   Administrator (64-bit)" WIndows OS pref pane, and used the role
   PUBLIC as suggested, but still receive the same error.

Any suggestions?

Also, does snowflake provide technical support, or are users left to post in public forums for technical support? A bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the following to grant the role to the user

```
GRANT ROLE POWERBI_ROLE TO USER POWERBI_USER_ACCOUNT
```

Looks like the article is missing this step.

Snowflake does provide tech support, you need to work with your account rep to set it up.